# Finding unconditional expectation using iterated expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Discrete random variable $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed between 1 and 100. Given $\Theta$ discrete random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed between 1 and $\Theta$. Show that

$E[X^2] = \frac{1}{100}\sum\limits_{x=1}^{100} x^2 \bigg(\sum\limits_{\theta=x}^{100} \frac{1}{\theta}\bigg)$

How to use $E[E[X^2|\Theta]]=E[X^2]$ to get the answer. Thank you

Comment: So what have you tried so far? For example, what is $E[X^2 \mid \Theta=\theta]$?

Comment: It should be $\sum\limits_{\theta=x}^{100} x^2 \frac{1}{\theta}$. In my opinion

Comment: No - it should be $\sum\limits_{x=1} ^ \theta x^2 \frac1\theta$.  Can you find what that is?  Then try $\sum\limits_{\theta=1} ^ {100} \left(\sum\limits_{x=1} ^ \theta x^2 \frac1\theta\right) \frac1{100}$

Comment: Agreed for the first limit but the second equation is not clear. We are taking expectation of the first equation sum is ranging for $\theta$ with it's pmf. How to reduce it to answer.

Comment: Thank you Henry got it Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Z$ are discrete, then
$$
E(X) = E(E(X \mid Z)) \mathop{=}^{\mathrm{def}} \sum_z E(X \mid Z = z) P(Z = z).
$$
If you know $E(X \mid Z = z) = u(z),$ then
$$
E(X) = \sum_z u(z) P(Z = z).
$$
Now apply this result replacing the appropriate values.